# how to translate @elements.infos in the field template

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, playframework-2.0

I'm looking for a way to translate the "Required" message to portuguese or to any html I want to, to add an icon for example, any suggestions on this ?

this is the field template I'm using :

```
<div class="clearfix @if(elements.hasErrors) {error} control-group">

    <label class="control-label" for="@elements.id">@elements.label</label>

    <div class="input controls">

        @elements.input

        <span class="help-inline">@elements.infos.mkString(", ")</span> 

        <span class="errors badge badge-important">@elements.errors.mkString(", ")</span>

    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you wrap the @elements.infos in a `Messages()` call:

```
<span class="help-inline">@elements.infos.map(i => Messages(i)).mkString(", ")</span>
```

or if you are talking about Play's default `required` messages, then you'll have to specify `error.required` in your `messages` file (though I'm not sure if this actually works in 2.0.x).

Comment: great forgot that I can use Messages over there too !! :P